# My script to convert Google Form to Docs does not change the body of the document

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function HPURequestForm(e) {

    var Timestamp = e.values[0]; var LastName = e.values[1]; var FirstName = e.values[2]; var MiddleInitial = e.values[3]; var DepartmentOffice = e.values[4]; var Designation = e.values[5]; var ContactNo = e.values[6]; var EmailAddress = e.values[7]; var HealthProgram = e.values[8]; var Request = e.values[9];
    
    var TemplateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1WBvocCTAmno4t7A2ShJO5K-tYTlr3fTW"); var TemplateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1wBxGNMAoQnEgOdvzATUCSfZW44EJv8kY");
    
    var copy = TemplateFile.makeCopy(LastName + ',' + FirstName, TemplateResponseFolder);
    
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    
    var body = doc.getBody();
    
    body.replaceText("{{LN}}", LastName); body.replaceText("{{FN}}", FirstName);  body.replaceText("{{MI}}", MiddleInitial);  body.replaceText("{{DO}}", DepartmentOffice);  body.replaceText("{{D}}", Designation);  body.replaceText("{{CN}}", ContactNo);  body.replaceText("{{EA}}", EmailAddress);  body.replaceText("{{HP}}", HealthProgram);  body.replaceText("{{R}}", Request); 
    
    doc.saveAndClose();

}
```

Comment: This code is rather in a mess, and I'd say that if it is like this on your development machine, it is rather hard to read. Could you amend it so that you have one statement per line?

Answer (score 0):

The string passed to the `replaceText` function of the Body class in Apps Script, must be valid RE2 regex:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement

You would most likely need to escape your curly braces - for example:

```
body.replaceText("\\{\\{LN\\}\\}", LastName)
```